# Angular 7 currency price

Tags: angular, angular6

estoy intentando dar formato a una moneda. Lo tengo que hacer en el componente.

En el template si se puede hacer con:

```
{{price | currency:'EUR':true:'1.2'}}
```

Pero como se podria hacer en el componente?
Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En Angular versión 6 y posteriores ya no es necesario [inyectar el Pipe como antes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components), ahora puedes directamente importar la función que el Pipe usa, en tu caso la función [`formatCurrency`](https://angular.io/api/common/formatCurrency)

```
formatCurrency(10.9 ,'es-ES','€','1.2');
```

Para que esto funcionara tuve que asegurarme de que el locale estaba registrado:

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeEs from '@angular/common/locales/es';

registerLocaleData(localeEs);
```

Puedes verlo funcionar [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pawer13-angular-currency) (StackBlitz)

Comment: Gracias por l'ayuda! Me sale esto 1,80�EUR. Se podria quedar solo con 1,80?

Answer (score 2):

puedes usar una función como:

```
getCurrency(price: number) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'}).format(price);
}
```

Comment: No es la solución que da Angular, pero es totalmente válida y soportada por todos los navegadores *actuales* (incluso IE 11).

Comment: La solución ideal es usar el locale como bien explicas en tu respuesta pero esto es más una solución quick&dirty. Si el requisito es a nivel de aplicación es mucho mejor registrar los locales. Esta guía me fue de ayuda también: https://angular.io/guide/i18n